# How to update 2 Views with different Parameters from 1 Controller

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Say we have Parent controller "P" and 2 children: "A" and "B".

"A" controller has input and used in "P" template twice with different parameters:

```
    <A-app [input]='param1'></A-app>
    <A-app [input]='param1'></A-app>
    <B-app (flag)="onClick($event)"></B-app>
```

"B" controller contains a button.
If I click in "B" template on this button, I emit from "B" controller a "flag", which triggers `onClick($event)` in a "P" controller.

This `onClick($event)` dedicated to change value in "A" controller via @ViewChild function call from "A" controller (like this:`this.componentA.changeAPar();`)

So I need to change value in "A" controller via click on the button in "B" controller template.

That scheme works fine only with one usage of a selector:

```
    <A-app [input]='param1'></A-app> //<---- 1 usage
    <B-app (flag)="onClick($event)"></B-app>
```

If I use selector 2 times, then parameter updates, but renders only in a first instance.

How to make this work?

**update**:
the same effect if I use shorthand in a "P" template to connect "A" and "B":

```
<A-app #a-app [input]='param1'></A-app>
<A-app #a-app [input]='param1'></A-app>
<B-app (flag)="#a-app.changeAPar()"></B-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for here is the [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) life-cycle hook. In your "A" component, you can subscribe to changes that occur on the `input` parameter and react accordingly. It would look something like this:

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'A',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `// omited for brevity`
})

export class AComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() input: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: any }) {
        if (changes['input'] && changes['input'].currentValue) {
            // handle change
        }
    }
}
```

Component B

```
import {Component, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'B',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `// omited for brevity`
})

export class BComponent {
    @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<string>();

    click(aValue: string):void {
        this.onClick.emit(aValue);
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AComponent, BComponent} from '...'

@Component({
    selector: 'P',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `
        <A [input]='param1'></A-app>
        <A [input]='param1'></A-app>
        <B (onClick)="onClick($event)"></B-app>`
})

export class PComponent {
    param1: string = '';

    onClick(aValue: string):void {
        this.param1 = aValue;
    }
}
```

This way, any changes made to `input` in the parent component will be caught and handled by `ngOnChanges`.

*NOTE*: Written from memory and not tested.